# Memory problems using bigmemory to load large dataset in R

Tags: r, bigdata, r-bigmemory

I have a large text file (>10 million rows, > 1 GB) that I wish to process one line at a time to avoid loading the entire thing into memory. After processing each line I wish to save some variables into a `big.matrix` object. Here is a simplified example:

```
library(bigmemory)
library(pryr)

con  <- file('x.csv', open = "r")
x <- big.matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 1, type = 'integer')

for (i in 1:5){
   print(c(address(x), refs(x)))
   y <- readLines(con, n = 1, warn = FALSE)
   x[i] <- 2L*as.integer(y)
} 

close(con)
```

where `x.csv` contains

```
4
18
2
14
16
```

Following the advice here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html I have printed the memory address of my `big.matrix` object and it appears to change with each loop iteration:

```
[1] "0x101e854d8" "2"          
[1] "0x101d8f750" "2"          
[1] "0x102380d80" "2"          
[1] "0x105a8ff20" "2"          
[1] "0x105ae0d88" "2"
```

1. Can `big.matrix` objects be modified in place?
2. is there a better way to load, process and then save these data? The current method is slow!

Comment: I would check out the `data.table` package. It is designed for "big" data (or least larger data).

Comment: General comment: R operates completely in memory, so if your final data set is more than the memory allocated for your R console, you may have a problem.

Comment: @Tim, I will try filebacked.big.matrix() to avoid exceeding my RAM allocation.

Comment: @Richard I'm not aware of an option in read.table to process input one line at a time.

Comment: @SeamusO'Bairead, With `data.table` you might be able to avoid reading in your data one line at a time. Also, using a `data.table` __might__ handle memory better than `big.matrix`. Last, if I recall, the `fread` function on wasn't working so I had to install `data.table` from git hib. If you try `fread` and it doesn't work, that would be my first trouble shooting step.

Answer (score 2):

> 2. is there a better way to load, process and then save these data? The current method is slow!

The slowest part of your method appearts to be making the call to read each line individually. We can 'chunk' the data, or read in several lines at a time, in order to not hit the memory limit while possibly speeding things up.

Here's the plan:

1. Figure out how many lines we have in a file
2. Read in a chunk of those lines
3. Perform some operation on that chunk
4. Push that chunk back into a new file to save for later

   ```
   library(readr) 
   # Make a file
   x <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000),100000,10))

   write_csv(x,"./test_set2.csv")

   # Create a function to read a variable in file and double it
   calcDouble <- function(calc.file,outputFile = "./outPut_File.csv",
   read.size=500000,variable="X1"){
     # Set up variables
     num.lines <- 0
     lines.per <- NULL
     var.top <- NULL
     i=0L

     # Gather column names and position of objective column
     connection.names <- file(calc.file,open="r+")
     data.names <- read.table(connection.names,sep=",",header=TRUE,nrows=1)
     close(connection.names)
     col.name <- which(colnames(data.names)==variable)

     #Find length of file by line
     connection.len <- file(calc.file,open="r+")
     while((linesread <- length(readLines(connection.len,read.size)))>0){

       lines.per[i] <- linesread
       num.lines <- num.lines + linesread
       i=i+1L 
     }
     close(connection.len)

     # Make connection for doubling function
     # Loop through file and double the set variables
     connection.double <- file(calc.file,open="r+")
     for (j in 1:length(lines.per)){

       # if stops read.table from breaking
       # Read in a chunk of the file
       if (j == 1) {
         data <- read.table(connection.double,sep=",",header=FALSE,skip=1,nrows=lines.per[j],comment.char="")
       } else {
         data <- read.table(connection.double,sep=",",header=FALSE,nrows=lines.per[j],comment.char="")
       }
         # Grab the columns we need and double them
         double <- data[,I(col.name)] * 2
       if (j != 1) {
         write_csv(data.frame(double),outputFile,append = TRUE)
       } else {
         write_csv(data.frame(double),outputFile)
       }

       message(paste0("Reading from Chunk: ",j, " of ",length(lines.per)))
     }
     close(connection.double)
   }

   calcDouble("./test_set2.csv",read.size = 50000, variable = "X1")
   ```

So we get back a .csv file with the manipulated data. You can change `double <- data[,I(col.name)] * 2` to whatever thing you need to do to each chunk.

Comment: @Steve_Corring thanks I'll do some benchmarks and get back to you. Also write_csv should be write.csv.

Comment: @Steve_Corrin, you are correct that the file reading by line is the slow part but your first statement about in-place modification is incorrect.  A `big.matrix` refers to a block of memory that has been mapped.  When you change an element you change it in that memory block so any other objects pointing to that memory reflect the change.  The memory address that is returned during each iteration is a copy of the pointer, not the matrix itself.

Comment: @cdeterman My mistake. I assumed big.matrix used some sort of out-of-memory approach to handle large data sets. Just looked over the docs and removed my answer to the first question. Thanks for the check

Comment: @Steve_Corrin, if using the `filebacked.backed.matrix` option then it is out-of-memory.  However, it is designed to still modify that matrix in-place (given that the `filebacked` object refers to a separate temp file).  The idea is to create as little overhead as possible, prevent copies (unless explicit) and allow for objects larger than available RAM.